# How to read from Node PassThrough stream after writing ends?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

How do I write to a Node Passthrough stream, then later read that data? When I try, the code hangs as though no data is sent. Here's a minimal example (in Typescript):

```
    const stream = new PassThrough();
    stream.write('Test chunk.');
    stream.end();

    // Later
    const chunks: Buffer[] = [];
    const output = await new Promise<Buffer>((resolve, reject) => {
        stream.on('data', (chunk) => { 
            chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk));}
        );
        stream.on('error', (err) => reject(err));
        stream.on('end', () => {
            resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks));
        });
    });
```

Please note that I can't attach the event listeners before writing to the stream: I don't know at the time of writing how I'm going to be reading from it. My understanding of a Transform stream like PassThrough was that it "decoupled" the Readable from the Writable, so that you could access them asynchronously.

Comment: Your code works for me, the promise resolves to a buffer containing `Test chunk.`. Or what do you mean by "Later"?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen, hmm... maybe it's something to do with Jest? I'm running that code in a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me, the promise resolves to a buffer containing `"Test chunk."`.

It will fail, however, if the readable side of the stream has already started emitting data when the `stream.on('data', (chunk) => {...})` is executed. I could force such a behavior by enclosing the `// Later` part of your code in a `setTimeout` *and* inserting an additional

```js
stream.on("data", () => {});
```

before that. This command will cause the stream to start emitting. Could that have happened in your case?

To be on the safe side, end the "early" part of your code with `stream.pause()` and begin the "later" part with `stream.resume()`, for example:

```js
const output = await new Promise<Buffer>((resolve, reject) => {
  stream.resume();
  stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
...
```

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because your comment led me to the answer. It turns out I was mocking the stream include, so it didn't actually do anything.